# Chatter in Apex: is it DML?

Tags: chatter, dml, connect-api

So there's times you can't DML (getters, constructors, components without allow DML, etc).

Can we use chatter in apex, or is that also considered inserting records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a quick test using the ConnectAPI, and looks like it is treated as DML

This code on a page produces the following error as expected:

> System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed

```
public with sharing class ChatterDML {

private final Account account;

    public ChatterDML (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.account = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        account.Name = 'Test Chatter Update';
        try{
        update account;
        //ConnectAPI.FeedItem fi = ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.PostFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, account.Id, 'New Name is ' + account.Name);
       }
        catch (Exception Ex) {
       }
   }
}
```

But this code calling the ConnectAPI also generates a DML error:

> System.LimitException: ConnectApi:DML currently not allowed

I assume the ConnectAPI label is appended to the error because it runs in the ConnectAPI namespace

```
public with sharing class ChatterDML {

    private final Account account;

        public ChatterDML (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
            this.account = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
            account.Name = 'Test Chatter Update';
            try{
            ConnectAPI.FeedItem fi = ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.PostFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, account.Id, 'New Name is ' + account.Name);
           }
            catch (Exception Ex) {
           }
       }
    }
```